# How to fill colors to the points in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, kinect

I have developed kinect application for handtracking in Visual Studio C#.Now I have to fill color wherever my hand is moving.As per my knowledge I have to get the X-Y coordinate of hand and fill the color in xaml. Can anyone tell me how to do it in xaml.(As I'm not much familiar with xaml)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to bind Fill property to changing coordinates? Maybe some bool, what goes in true when you in moving.

Comment: no, I don't know how to do it. I'm a beginner. please help me out.